# Log file rotation name

Tags: c, string

I have written this simple C program that changes the rotation file name.
Eg:  For `A_B_C_1` Need to rotate it to `A_B_C_2`and if `A_B_C` need to rotate it to `A_B_C_1`

Problem is the `strncat` is not working as expectedly. It is giving me output like:

```
A_B_C_1 (Works fine for single instance)
A_B_C_2
A_B_C_23
A_B_C_2324
```

Logic used is simple:
- get the last digit in the string if it exists.
- If it does not simply append _1 (This one is working fine)
- If it does - extract the number, increment it and append to the new string.

Is there some std library that does this?

Gives error on calling this method in a loop / multiple times....

I am not able to debug the cause..... Need help on this,Please guide.

```
   int getRotationFileName(char *sFileName,char *sNewFileName)
   {
   char sTmpFile[256];
    int newRotation;
    memset(sTmpFile,NULL,sizeof(sTmpFile));
    strncpy(sTmpFile, sFileName, strlen(sFileName));
    char *tokenPtr;
    strtok(sFileName,"_"); //a
    strtok(NULL, "_"); //b
    strtok(NULL, "_"); //c
    tokenPtr = strtok(NULL, "_"); //1
        printf("sTempFile [%s], sFileName [%s], token [%s]",
            sTmpFile,sFileName,tokenPtr);


    if(tokenPtr!= NULL)//Last - exists
    {

        newRotation = atoi(tokenPtr);
        int newLen = strlen(sTmpFile);
        int oneLen = strlen(tokenPtr);
        memset(sNewFileName, NULL, sizeof(sNewFileName));
        printf("sNewFileName is prior: %s and len is %d \n", 
        sNewFileName, (newLen-oneLen));
        printf("sTempName is prior: %s", sTmpFile);
    strncpy(sNewFileName,sTmpFile, (newLen-oneLen));

        printf("diff is %d\n", (newLen-oneLen));
        printf("sNewFileName before concat %s \n", sNewFileName);
        newRotation++;
        sprintf(sNewFileName,"%s%d",sNewFileName, newRotation);
        sNewFileName[strlen(sNewFileName)]='\0';
        printf("sNewFileName after concat %s \n", sNewFileName);
    }
    else
    {
        printf("in else TmpFile [%s] , New File [%s], len %d",sTmpFile,
     sNewFileName,strlen(sTmpFile));
        strcat(sTmpFile,"_1");
        strncpy(sNewFileName,sTmpFile, strlen(sTmpFile));
    }
    strcpy(sFileName, sNewFileName);
    printf("\nNew file created is %s\n",sNewFileName);
    return 1;
```

}

Seems to be a problem on line: strncpy(sNewFileName,sTmpFile, (newLen-oneLen));

Feedback: The code formatter is not working correctly on this site for Chrome browser

Comment: The formatting on your source code is pretty messed up... to post code, simply make sure it is indented four spaces.

Comment: I had fixed it, but the fix was reverted, I think that's what the Chrome "feedback" line refers to. Weird. A fixed-up version is in the edit history, feel free to re-apply it. :)

Comment: Small Update: There can be digits in the initial name and I have to check for two underscores before appending the last underscore with  the incremented digit if needed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is ... A bit messy. You need to split your algorithm into steps, each of which should be easy to perforM:

- Check if the name ends in a number. If it does, record where the number started, and extract the number. If it didn't, act as if it ended with 0.
- Increment the number.
- Create a new string by concatenating the prefix and the number (as a string).

Please note that these algorithms are racy, generally it's a better idea to let the standard library generate a unique name for you.

Here's one solution:

```
void rotateName(const char *oname, char *nname)
{
    const char  *ptr;
    int         number, plen;

    for(ptr = oname; *ptr && !isdigit(*ptr); ptr++)
            ;
    if(*ptr == '\0')
            number = 0;
    else
            number = atoi(ptr);
    plen = ptr - oname;
    if(plen <= 0)
            return;
    memcpy(nname, oname, plen);
    sprintf(nname + plen, "%d", number + 1);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

use e.g.

```
int get_rotated_name(char *filename,char *rotatedname,size_t len)
{
    int version = 0;
    int pos = strrchr(filename,'_');

    if(pos == -1)
      return 1;
    if(isdigit(filename[pos+1])) {
      version = atoi(&filename[pos+1];
      filename[pos] = 0;
   }

   version++;
   snprintf(rotatedname,len,"%s_%d",filename,version);

  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You do not need all that `strtok` activity for a constant filename string.

- Either compare the constant part with a `strncmp` to confirm it, or use a `sscanf`
- Pull out the file number integer with an `atoi` or a `sscanf %d`
- Do your comparisons and change the integer (with modulus operations, etc)
- Generate the new name with `sprintf` using the new integer

---

And, if you do not need to actually generate the next file name from the previously passed as your function suggests, simply keep a constant string and an rotating integer which is used with the `sprintf` to generate the next file name.
I understand that may not be usable in all cases.

Answer (score 0):

Do you really want to rotate the sequence number also?.

I would suggest not to do that and keep incrementing your file name constant with sequence number it will help to know how many files have been opened.

Parallaly you can maintain array of files-names, and rotate the start-index and  end-index and increment the start-index every time you open new file. when array gets filled just remove the file at end-index and go on.

Answer (score 0):

I would look at the end of the string, and if it's a number, I'd keep going back until I reach a non-numeric character, adding these to a string, and keeping the position (p).

- 'filename' => ''
- 'filename_9' => '9'
- 'filename-3786' => '3786'

I'd then convert it to a number n, if it's empty, I'd assume a zero.

I would take the original string up to p, convert n+1 to a string and concatenate it.

- 'filename' => 'filename2'
- 'filename_9' => 'filename_10'
- 'filename-3786' => 'filename-3787'

You could also look for separators at the p-th character like ' ', '_', '-', and remove them, then always add a fixed separator like _.

Answer (score 0):

> Is there some std library that does this?

i would use logrotate (https://linux.die.net/man/8/logrotate) instead of reinventing the wheel.

you just need to install a sigusr1 handler that close and reopen the log file.  logrotate will rotate/rename/compress the file for you.

if you don't like to use sigusr1 handler, or have used it for something else, then you can implement a file existence check inside the log routine.  If the log file has disappeared which means logrotate has occurred: close the file and reopen it with the same name.

happy logging.